# How to handle multiple ruby services in gRPC server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grpc

Developing gRPC based services in a rails project. Suppose I have two services `ProductService` and `UserService` implementation.

My GRPC server code:

```
server = GRPC::RpcServer.new
server.add_http2_port([ENV['GRPC_HOST'], ENV['GRPC_PORT']].join(':'), :this_port_is_insecure)
server.handle(AuthService) # I cannot pass like server.handle([AuthService, UserService]
server.run_till_terminated
```

As I can read under [GRPC ruby source code input](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/a85b78baa69a57b724d6cfe35a1dadb9719f2c56/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/rpc_server.rb) to `handle` method expects service to be either a class that includes `GRPC::GenericService` and whose new function can be called without argument or any instance of such a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document for gRPC in ruby doesn't clarify but try this:

```
require 'YOUR_auth_service'
require 'YOUR_user_service'

server = GRPC::RpcServer.new
server.add_http2_port([ENV['GRPC_HOST'], ENV['GRPC_PORT']].join(':'), :this_port_is_insecure)
server.handle(AuthService)
server.handle(UserService) # THIS IS THE ADDTION TO ABOVE CODE
server.run_till_terminated
```